# When is the autopilot engaged and disengaged?

Tags: airline-operations, autopilot

When does the pilot engage the autopilot during a flight? And when does he disengage it - e.g. at what height - during the descent?

Comment: Welcome Adam. Your question is not bad, but has been likely already answered in: [On modern commercial airliners, how much of the flight could be fully taken care of by the auto pilot?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/)

Comment: It could be broken into sections for ease of reading and answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a B777 pilot. On departure, we generally hand fly until about 10,000' to keep up our skills. If the departure procedure is complicated, we will ask for the AP on at 200' so there is no chance of messing up the departure procedure.

On approach I typically disconnect the Autopilot at about 1500' AGL once visual contact is assured and I am inside the Final Approach fix.

If there is any chance of a possible missed approach due to weather, or other conflicting aircraft, on the runway or elsewhere, I will leave the AP on until there is virtually no chance of a missed approach.

Most of the pilots I fly with tend to do the same.