# Is it possible to integrate an AI CoPilot on existing planes?

Tags: aircraft-design, artificial-intelligence

Or a new aircraft would have to be designed for such a thing? I have little knowledge of aviation, so please feel free to fill me in the required bits.

Comment: What is an "AI Copilot"? And how does it differ from a regular autopilot?

Comment: To make decisions for which you need a human inside the cockpit. It would turn the human pilot's role largely supervisory. It would be, as Canuk said, acting on its own high-probability inferences.

Comment: I think the bigger question is if we can safely integrate the already working software used in Unmanned Aircraft Systems/Aerial Vehicles into the Commercial sector. Obviously we would not literally use the same software, but the ideas and methods that have been proven to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your question as: "do we have yet the required interfaces for a computer to fully interact with an aircraft". This is indeed the prerequisite before any intelligent system can pilot an aircraft.

That means could we yet plug a system into some bus to receive all signals available to a human pilot and send all commands a human pilot can issue.

The answer is no (e.g. a computer cannot lower the gears or receive electronic signals from the wet compass), but the required updates are not so large and involve limited retrofitting.

Of course, we don't have this computer yet, but this kind of software is not a huge step either (and anyway this is not in the scope of your question).

Would such system be economically profitable for an airline in term of safety, certification, operational cost, software maintenance, compared to a human first officer? If the answer is yes, then this is a matter of maybe 10 years before a full electronic pilot is tested. I doubt the answer is yes, it could be useful, but it will have an additional cost, so there could be a long time before we see it in a cockpit.

Comment: Aside from lowering the gear (which has been done, the Russian Space Shuttle Buran comes to mind, since at least the 1970's), a full auto-landing is conducted regularly. What we don't have yet is ground control (taxi in/out) and auto-take-off.

Comment: @RonBeyer Indeed, I am shocked to learn that lowering the landing gear is *still* not automatic, and one of the risks of flying is a gear-up landing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belly_landing

Comment: @RonBeyer: Starting with [STS-121](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-121), each US orbiter had also a  [RCO IFM](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2006/06/rco-saving-a-crippled-discovery/) cable on-board. This cable could be used to connect different systems, so that commands for a complete automatic landing could be sent from the Mission Command Center in Houston.

Comment: @mins Interesting, didn't know that the orbiter had that, but it doesn't look like it was ever used, and I'm not sure that it is an autonomous system (requires operators in Houston). The [Boeing X-37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-37) says that it is the second spacecraft with auto-land capabilities after the Buran.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Piper used to have an auto-extend feature. See http://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/20-things-you-never-knew-about-your-airplane-or-someone-elses/#.WO3SkIjyuUk, item 4, for why they discontinued it. If I bought an airplane with the auto-extend feature, I would disable it. The decision  as to when it's best to drop the gear is not always a straight forward one. It's a matter of opinion, but mine is that I'm willing to trust my ability to get the gear down rather than forego flexibility.

Answer (score 12):

*If* an "AI Co-pilot" existed, it could likely be integrated on existing airplanes with an auto-pilot system.

Since your question is a little vague, I'm going to take a stab at some your hidden assumptions and go from there. I'm also making the assumption that you're talking about the *enroute* phase of flight, and leaving the taxiing, take-off and landing in the hands of the human pilot.

At the risk of (extreme) oversimplifying, an AI system is essentially something that takes in a lot of data, analyzes it (through different algorithms) and outputs data that can then be used to do *something.*

I'm going to assume that the AI algorithm is supervised and has been trained on a bunch of existing data, and it has been figured out what data is important to make high-probability inferences.

In-flight, there are multiple sources of data that could be fed to the AI algorithm for it to make probabilistic inferences on what it should do.  These data sources are things like:

- Engine monitors (my EDM 700 I think logs 60 data points/second on things such as cylinder head temperature, exhaust gas temperature, RPM, location, power setting, etc.)
- GPS Receivers (3D position)
- AHRS (attitude information)
- ADS-B (Traffic and Weather)
- On-board Weather Radar
- XM Satellite Weather

(As an aside, [SavvyAnalysis](https://www.savvyanalysis.com/home) already does a bit of this type of analysis using the data from your engine monitor).

So, provided that your "AI Co-pilot" has been properly trained in advance on the same type of data that you are able get from your airplane while in-flight, your AI Co-pilot could ingest the data, and output signals to the auto-pilot which would then fly the airplane. The autopilot controller is simply sending information to a particular servo for a particular control surface (aileron, elevator, etc.) and if your AI Co-pilot can output the same signal, then it could control the servos the same as the autopilot.

One of the (many) difficulties lies in designing the system to safely handle things that it hasn't seen in the training data.

But to answer your question, it wouldn't require the design of a new *aircraft*, but rather a new *autopilot control system.*

**EDIT: Extra thoughts**

After thinking about your question some more, I was thinking why you might want an AI Co-pilot? I'm thinking the answer to that might would be for it to either make decisions for you that you are unaware you should be making or to help you make better decisions.  There is existing software that does something like this, called [Xavion](http://xavion.com/app/full-description/), which continually figures out where you should land if your engine quits based on the current location and performance of your airplane. It's not hooked up to an autopilot, but it wouldn't be too far of a stretch to think that sometime in the future, something like this could be a part of the autopilot controller.

> Furthermore, Xavion is constantly running engine-out flight
>   simulations behind-the-scenes as you fly. The app imagines an engine
>   failure every single second, and it checks how your plane would do in
>   a power-off glides to every runway at every airport in gliding range.
>
> For each of these simulated engine failures, Xavion estimates the
>   likelihood of a successful landing based on the runway’s length,
>   width, proximity to the aircraft, and glide path from your current
>   location down to the threshold of that runway. When Xavion has found
>   the runway that it believes is most likely to result in a safe
>   engine-out landing, it builds a series of hoops from your current
>   location to that runway—spiraling, circling, or extending as needed in
>   order for the hoops to follow a constant descent angle that your
>   airplane should be able to sustain without power.

When you start to think of something like this, you can start to imagine analyzing real-time weather data and having the system make (or help make) a decision to divert or land based on your performance and experience. However, this is all something that would happen in the auto-pilot controller, so retrofitting it to an airplane with an existing autopilot would be more of a software upgrade than a hardware redesign.

**UPDATE:**

[Wired had a good article on this on 3/28/2017](https://www.wired.com/2017/03/ai-wields-power-make-flying-safer-maybe-even-pleasant/?mbid=social_fb_onsiteshare). It talks about all the different sources of data that could be used to make an AI learn about the airplane, figure out where the holes are in the data and who could fill them.  An interesting place for data that I didn't think about (because it's not data generated *in flight*), is maintenance and service logs.

Particularly relevant to the intent (I think) of your question might be this passage:

> Elsewhere, researchers are working to ensure AI can help pilots manage
>   crises as they arise. At University College London, a team led by
>   Haitham Baomar and Peter Bentley is developing a new autopilot system
>   that learns how to manage emergencies by watching how well-trained
>   pilots do so, and then behaving as they do in similar circumstances.
>
> “We want to increase safety by trying to tackle the human-error factor
>   that might be caused by stress, information overload, and sometimes a
>   lack of sufficient and up-to-date training,” Baomar says. “Modern
>   autopilots, unfortunately, can’t handle challenging flight conditions
>   such as severe weather conditions or system failures.”

Comment: Anecdote comment: First time subway come full auto people are scared of boarding a train without a conductor. For the airliners co. a AI Copilot can cause some marketing concerns

Comment: @jean I think people might have less problems with a system where an actual human pilot is still in the cockpit and able to take over at a moment's notice should something go wrong, than with a full-automatic system with no human pilot with "skin in the game". I think we have a question somewhere on completely automated passenger flights which discusses some of those issues; a case could probably be made that *combining* the good parts of technology and human pilots make for an overall improvement. Of course, that doesn't address the similarities between OP's proposal and eg modern autopilots.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I believe that this is the questions that you are referring to: [Why do we still use pilots to fly airplanes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1802/69)

Comment: @Lnafziger Yes, that looks like it's the one. Thanks!

Comment: That Xavion software sounds like a tremendous asset! It looks to solve a problem that seems to be happening with decreasing frequency, but I can see where it would be a great benefit to the pilots to recognize that they have an engine out, push a button, and a prepared solution pops up instantly. While pilots/ATC are cool as a cucumber, it would take away a lot of the stress and increase the likelihood of a safe outcome from an engine out situation.

Answer (score 2):

We already have this - it's called the autopilot.

The autopilot has gone through continuous improvement.  Modern ones are hooked up to GPS, can control the throttles for optimum fuel efficiency, and so on.  They're a very sophisticated bit of kit.

More recently, autoland is standard on large aircraft, and is becoming more common on smaller passenger aircraft.  Again, these vary in sophistication, up to full "zero-zero" landing completely under the autopilot's control.

Comment: Same for military planes too?

Comment: *"More recently, autoland is standard on large aircraft"* Recently as in the [late 60's and early 70's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoland)? Autoland has been around for more than 50 years.

Comment: @RonBeyer More recently than the original autopilot. :)  And it became standard more recently than that.

Comment: An autopilot won't abort the landing if there is a runway incursion. A human will do it, and that's what is expected from an intelligent autopilot. Intelligent autopilot is as different from autopilot than cruise control is different from a self driving car.

Comment: @mins It's not exactly different - it's adding extra features.  Cruise control does *some* of what a regular driver does.  Adaptive cruise control does a bit more.  Lane assist, ABS, active collision detection, auto-park, all those things do a bit more, and it'll be the same for autopilots too.  It's entirely possible to break the task down into chunks and solve each one in turn, so your AI copilot becomes progressively more helpful.  The eventual goal should be full automated control, because a properly-programmed system will be more reliable than a human being, but we're still getting there.

Comment: @mins On cruise control, its state is based on current inputs but also on previous inputs and previous states, so your first statement is untrue.  For an autopilot, all that's needed to reduce the pilot to a supervisory role (which is what the OP specifically asks for) is full control over all phases of flight.  The learning phase ***MUST*** happen during development only, because that's the only way this is safe.  Once it's installed, there's no more learning needed or wanted.

Comment: @Graham: As soon as you switch to AI (and that's [a big debate](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-30290540) today), you can't think the same way than with deterministic automation. If you learn from experience to improve as do humans, then "*The learning phase MUST happen during development only, because that's the only way this is safe*" is indeed a thing of the past. Cf. [this case](https://www.ibm.com/think/marketing/how-watson-learns/) for permanent learning (permanent addition to corpus of knowledge).

Comment: @mins My point is that this is *not* a thing of the past.  When it comes to carrying out a narrowly-focussed task repeatably and reliably, this is precisely what you want.  There are well-bounded areas where the system *should* learn, for example how much rudder control is necessary to compensate for cross-winds, but these are easily covered by well-defined strategies such as Kalman filters.  Your links cite examples of learning which have no relevance to this task, and applying these principles in a situation where they are actively dangerous would be gross incompetence and must not be used.

Comment: @Graham maybe I'm misreading you, but the equivalent to your "The learning phase MUST happen during development only, because that's the only way this is safe." statement is equivalent to "The pilot must only use what he learned in the classroom because those are the correct theories, anything else is unsafe." I'm not a pilot, but everything I've read about flying (and everything else in life) is that theories are good but practical experience is _far_ better. An AI begins with a set of assumptions but learns from experience to make it better, just as humans do-hence _artificial_ intelligence.

Comment: @FreeMan That's a lot of assumptions though.  For starters, there's a reason pilots are type-certified, which is that randomly picking it up as you go is unsafe.  Instead you have a well-defined period of learning, after which you know what you can and can't do.  Similar, yes?  Then whatever practical skills you pick up are as a result of making mistakes and correcting them (or having someone feed back to you); but an AI has no way of knowing what constitutes a mistake, and there's no-one on the plane who can teach it, so it is fundamentally unable to learn that way.

Comment: @FreeMan But more than that, what automation brings to the party is not flexibility, it's 100% rock-solid deterministic behaviour.  A large proportion of incidents are due to pilot error, and that randomness is precisely what you do **NOT** want your autopilot to replicate.  More than that, there are incidents where something fails and the pilot doesn't know how to recover.  The autopilot can have those scenarios pre-programmed.  So that kind of learning really isn't needed or wanted.  It doesn't have to be perfect; but by being 100% reliable and **not** making it up on the fly, it's better.

Comment: @Graham: In case you want to know more about the current change in automation: [deep learning](https://medium.com/basic-income/deep-learning-is-going-to-teach-us-all-the-lesson-of-our-lives-jobs-are-for-machines-7c6442e37a49), and [how it can be used](http://airfactsjournal.com/2016/10/artificial-intelligence-boom-means-aviation/).

Comment: @mins Thank you for posting links which establish that what I'm saying is the case.  Both links state explicitly that an autopilot system would be be pre-taught a suite of scenarios based on existing data and existing situations.  As a software engineer who's spent roughly 15 of my 20 years' experience in safety-related engineering, I have some understanding of how utterly unsafe and illegal it would be to do anything else.