# What is the current state of research on Autonomous Air Traffic Control?

Tags: air-traffic-control, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to get informed about Autonomous Air Traffic Control. Communication is crucial in this field. I am aware that different possibilities exist to realize it, for example:

1. an ad-hoc network for aircraft-to-aircraft communication
2. an infrastructure-based communication system

of course infrastructure-based communication systems (meaning a geostationary satellite) include a high propagation delay.

Anyways, I am thinking about a good solution for this problem and am currently looking for research papers in this field. I figured, maybe someone here knows some good sources already?

Comment: what aircraft types are you referring to? For small quadcopter swarms, you'll find ad hoc networks, and if you're flying a Boeing 747 over the ocean, where you can't have infrastracture on the ground, half a second of plane-satellite-plane latency hardly matters at all, since you'd simply place planes far enough apart.

Comment: for aircraft to aircraft communication, you should read this [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43179/are-peer-to-peer-communications-feasible-between-aircraft)

Comment: TCAS seems to be really ad hoc :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean air to air? Or were you thinking of a ground system? What sort of traffic density?

If the former there are a number of concepts within the big medernisation programs like US NextGen, EU SESAR, Australian OneSky or Japan's CARATS programs.

ICAO has a global roadmap running to 2040.

VHF datalink mode 2 is up and running now, higher bandwidth satcom comming (Inmarsat SB-S/ Iris). VOIP likely to have some interesting latency effects in airspaces eith high R/T loads.

Significant global safety spectrum, ITU, regulatory, standardisation and other institutional and political challenges stand before a cool tech idea.

For spectrum look within current band allocations.

Aviation is generally incremental. Bear in mind thst your tech needs to be robust, globally portable.

If you can develop a regulstir accepted method to assure AI or ML apps then this would be a fertlle and lucrative area.