# Does the Flight Data Recorder store the data locally or send it to an offsite backup while in flight?

Tags: airline-operations, aircraft-systems, instrument-flight-rules, flight-data-recorder, flight-data-monitoring

I was wondering, what a black box actually does ? Does it store the in flight data, in case an accident should occur or it's sending it to an offsite backup while in flight ? And if it stores the data, how huge is it's size, cause I've heard airplanes are known to generate several terabytes of data during a flight.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1147/8730

Comment: TERRAbytes of data in a flight??? Not unless you had a huge number of high-def video cameras all running continuously. FDR’s capture a lot of data, but it isn’t near a terrabyte. They can capture & store all the flights over a week or two, which is downloaded at regular intervals by maintenance. And we aren’t talking server racks of hard drives here!

Comment: @RalphJ Well, some planes are generating 1/2 a terabyte on each flight, so at least he's in the right ballpark.  Take a look at the linked question/answer if you are curious.

Comment: @DanielKiracofe That is 10K per second, so well under 1 megabyte per minute. The trans-Pac flight of 12 hours is 720 minutes.  So well below half a GIGAbyte per flight, i.e. 200 orders of magnitude less than a TERAbyte.

Comment: @Lnafziger Looked at the linked article. While the IOT on a 787 might be generating that much data (the article was ***way*** short on specifics), nothing suggests that it is all going into the FDR. For example, data on who used which IFE channels & for how long is interesting, and exactly the sort of stuff the IOT can generate in great volume, but that wouldn’t be going into the FDR. I wouldn’t put too much stock in that 1 value mentioned without explanation in the 1 article.

Comment: @RalphJ Actually, you are correct, it says that the internet connected devices generate that much, but doesn't say that it is logged on the FDR.  Thanks!

Comment: @RalphJ, sorry I got my math wrong. you were right. I deleted my comment.